# 2sxc - creating a field for checkboxes

Tags: 2sxc

Is there any way to create a field with checkbox options? I can't seem to find anything on how to do that. I need to create a field that has predefined options where the user can select more than one of those options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a "checkbox group" feature, where your template would have something like an array of resulting items.

At the moment there is no predefined way of doing this. You could either create a bunch of checkboxes, or you could use an entity list. The UI may not be what you want, in which case you could create your own UI control to do that.

http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/custom-input-type-advanced-dynamic-data

Comment: Yep, checkbox group is what I had in mind. I'm just using several boolean fields for now so that will work since the checkbox group isn't an option. Thanks!